# Java match regex then format string using second regex

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to first match a string with a regex pattern and then use a second pattern to format that string. From what i've read up on, one way of achieving this is using `.replaceAll()` *(**edit**: `.replaceAll()` is not used for this purpose, read comments on answer for clarification)*

I have created this function whereby the aim is to:

1. Match given string to `match`
2. Format given string using `format` regex

   ```
   String match = "(^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}$)";
   String format = "(^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[*\\s\\\\][A-Z]{3}$)";
   String input = "YO11YOL"

   if (input.matches(match)) {
       return input.replaceAll(input, "??");
   }
   ```

The output should be `YO11 YOL` with a added space after the fourth character

Comment: If you're trying to replace the matches of `format` with something then you should use `input.replaceAll(format, something)`.

Comment: I'm using the `match` string (regex) to check whether the input is valid and then my aim is to use the `format` string (regex) to format the input string.

Comment: **AB12CDE** becomes **AB12 CDE** or **XY01ZAB** becomes **XY01 ZAB**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use two [**capturing groups**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and refer to them from the string replacement pattern with [**placeholders**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1` and `$2`:

```
String result = input.replaceFirst("^([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2})([A-Z]{3})$", "$1 $2");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tMJYms/1) and a diagram:

[image]

Note that `.replaceFirst` is enough (though you *may* also use `.replaceAll`) as there is only one replacement operation expected (the regex matches the whole string due to the `^` and `$` [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)).

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for, so if i were to add another capturing group, i'd just need to add an additional placeholder? So `$1 $2` becomes `$1 $2 $3` ?

Comment: @Sha-1 Yes, e.g. to get `YO 11 YOL` use `input.replaceFirst("^([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{2})([A-Z]{3})$", "$1 $2 $3")`

Answer (score 3):

This is what you want: Unfortunately it cannot be done the way that you want. But it can be done using **substring**.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String match = "(^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}$)";
    String input = "YO11YOL";

    if (input.matches(match)) {
       String out = input.substring(0, 4) + " " + input.substring(4, 7);
       System.out.println(out);
    }

}
```

Comment: What if i wanted to put a space after the first letter? So **is** becomes **i s**.

Comment: AH! You are misunderstanding replaceAll(). replaceAll does not replace one regex, with another. It replaces anything that matches the regex, with the **replacement** string.

Comment: the replacement string **can not be a regex expression**.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, it makes sense now! What would be the most efficient way of formatting the string using a regex?

Comment: I've edited to show you how to do it for the string **YO11YOL**. But it will only work for strings that are formatted the same. Youll have to modify it for strings that dont pass the regex you supplied.

Comment: **Update:** it can be done using `.replaceFirst()` as opposed to substrings, see answer which explains the use of capturing groups and placeholders.

Comment: `replaceAll` will also work, just there is no point even try multiple searches as the regex is meant to match the whole string.